# NSDateFormatter date from string correct format

Tags: nsdateformatter

I need to know how to get my string:  16/03/2012 1:15 PM

into an NSDate to add to calendar.

What would be the correct format for that?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert a NSString to NSDate:

```
NSString* myStringDate = @"16/03/2012 1:15 PM";

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a"];
NSDate *resultDate = [df dateFromString: myStringDate];
```